# Listing possible null dereference or forward null in CPP source code

Tags: static-analysis, static-code-analysis, clang-static-analyzer, cppcheck, coverity

Is there a tool which can do static analysis and find possible forward null and possible null dereference cases.
I know coverity is pretty much used and also cpp check.
But I dnt find it usefull when comes to user defined data-type comes to picture.

Please provide a solution which can handle user defined data types also and works on C++ code.

Comment: Maybe try over here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You might try

[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) - Cppcheck is a static analysis tool for C/C++ code. Unlike C/C++ compilers and many other analysis tools it does not detect syntax errors in the code. Cppcheck primarily detects the types of bugs that the compilers normally do not detect. The goal is to detect only real errors in the code (i.e. have zero false positives).

[Coverity-Scan](https://scan.coverity.com/) - STATIC ANALYSIS Find and fix defects in your Java, C/C++, C# or JavaScript open source project for free. Test every line of code and potential execution path.

There are a lot of other tools available, both open source and commercial.
Good luck.